# How good are the probabilities produced from Random Forest models?

Tags: probability, random-forest

As far as I know, for classification problems, there's generally a lack of a measure of probabilities in machine learning models, unless a customized probability structure is designed. Random forest, however, has a unique way of estimating probabilities, by counting the number of times a specific class is voted by trees, which I think is a byproduct of the model.

Here, my questions are how good these probabilities are and how much I can trust these probabilities, in places like betting, where the probabilities play an important role. Thanks.

Comment: What is a good probability?

Comment: Are you asking about whether these probabilities are well calibrated? [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) is an example and some discussion on calibration (or lack thereof) of probabilities obtained from Random Forest.

Comment: @Sycorax If we could rerun the experiment infinite times, the outcomes have an observed frequency close to the actual probability. That's the definition of probability, right? i.e., if the world described by random forest is the real world where the data generating process happens.

Comment: @darXider My question is if the probabilities are close the truth. Is calibration helping getting the probabilities closer to the truth?

Comment: @Maxareo That's not the **definition** of a probability. A probability just has to satisfy the Kolmogorov axioms. You're asking about whether the RF probabilities match the true class membership, i.e. calibration.

Comment: @Sycorax You are right, that's not the definition, that's the tool we use to measure a binary-number data-generating process. And yes, I'm asking how good this measure is to the ground truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't all that well-calibrated, but they're not terrible.  What you're looking for is [Platt scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling).  Basically, take the scores from the RF and fit a logitic regression to them.

Comment: Indeed, this is an approach calibrating machine learning models. The paper in the link seems to be very relevant. http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2005_Niculescu-MizilC05.pdf